# what is the interest of TimeDistributed after an LSTM layer?

Tags: time-series, lstm, prediction

I've already seen several similair questions but I did not understand anything,
what is the interest of TimeDistributed?
why we need to insert a TimeDistributed layer after LSTM to establish the time series prediction

Answer (score 5):

Ok let's say you have an `LSTM()` layer with `return_sequences = True` set. That means each LSTM cell in it is outputting its value. The output of the layer is therefore a sequence of outputs, not just the final one. That means the output is a processed time series, with sequential information in it.

You want `Dense()` layers to take this information and use it to process the signal further. In particular, you want some Dense architecture to process each of these sequential outputs one by one. By using the `TimeDistributed()` wrapper it's like if you're iterating the same `Dense()` architecture on this sequential output.

I typically use `TimeDistributed(Dense())` at the bottom of a seq2seq Decoder, in order produce the final output sequence.

Comment: This is the clearest explanation so far on the matter. Thank you very much. Can you please give an example what will happen if we apply, let us say TimeDis(Dense([100, 4, 16])) ? where [100, 4, 16] is the output of the last LSTM layer I have in my model?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean TimeDistributedDense? Anyway this should clear up you understanding in one way or other.

> TimeDistributedDense applies a same Dense (fully-connected) operation
>   to every timestep of a 3D tensor.
>
> The most common scenario for using TimeDistributedDense is using a
>   recurrent NN for tagging task.e.g. POS labeling or slot filling task.
>
> In this kind of task: For each sample, the input is a sequence
>   ($a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4...a_N$) and the output is a sequence ($b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4...b_N$)
>   with the same length. $b_i$ could be viewed as the label of $a_i$. Push $a_1$
>   into a recurrent neural net to get output $b_1$. Than push $a_2$ and the hidden
>   output of $a_1$ to get $b_2$...
>
> If you want to model this by Keras, you just need to used a
>   TimeDistributedDense after a RNN or LSTM layer(with
>   return_sequence=True) to make the cost function is calculated on all
>   time-step output. If you don't use TimeDistributedDense ans set the
>   return_sequence of RNN=False, then the cost is calculated on the last
>   time-step output and you could only get the last bN.

Also, here is a link for more info -> https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1029